# WP cli --path does not seem to work

Tags: wp-cli

WP-cli does not seem to work when adding a `--path` param

```
me@host:~$ wp plugin status --path=`/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html`
-bash: /home/me/domains/example.com/public_html: is a directory
Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress install.
Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.
```

If I `cd` to the dir and then run the command without the path it does work.
I have wp-cli 0.25

**Update**
Extra info when adding a `--debug` flag

```
Debug (bootstrap): No readable global config found (0.031s)
Debug (bootstrap): No project config found (0.032s)
Debug (bootstrap): No package autoload found to load. (0.39s)
Debug (bootstrap): ABSPATH defined: /home/me/domains/example.com/public_html/ (0.39s)
```

Anybody got a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Add "--debug" to your call and paste the output in your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's as if you were trying to run:

```
wp plugin status --path=$(/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html)
```

because what's inside the backticks get's evaluated.

[Here's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands) a good reading about using backticks in the command line.

Let me quote [@rozcietrzewiacz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27432/31912):

> **Backtick is not a quotation sign**, it has a very
>   special meaning. Everything you type between backticks is evaluated
>   (executed) by the shell before the main command [...]

Alternatives:

```
wp plugin status --path=/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html
wp plugin status --path="/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html"
wp plugin status --path='/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html'
```

When I use the [wp-skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) setup, I have to point to the `wp/` core folder, not the folder above it containing the `wp-config.php` file.

### Update:

Within the [Runner](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/44622856b90478ae5be36b2c7bb39f5fe0337e92/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php) class we have:

```
/**
 * Do WordPress core files exist?
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function wp_exists() {
    return is_readable( ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/version.php' );
}
```

and when we set `ABSPATH` with

```
--path=/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html/
```

it looks like we are using:

```
/**
 * Set WordPress root as a given path.
 *
 * @param string $path
 */
private static function set_wp_root( $path ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', rtrim( $path, '/' ) . '/' );
    WP_CLI::debug( 'ABSPATH defined: ' . ABSPATH, 'bootstrap' );
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = realpath( $path );
}
```

and then:

```
 is_readable( '/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html/wp-includes/version.php' )
```

becomes false because with the *wp-skeleton* setup, the core directory is:

```
/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html/wp/
```

This test is necessary but not sufficient. There are other tests, e.g. the  [`Runner::find_wp_root()`](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/44622856b90478ae5be36b2c7bb39f5fe0337e92/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L160) method.

The reason why it works when OP is located within:

```
/home/me/domains/example.com/public_html/
```

could be because of the [`Runner::extract_subdir_path()`](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/44622856b90478ae5be36b2c7bb39f5fe0337e92/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php#L136) method that scans the content of the `index.php` file with:

```
$index_code = file_get_contents( $index_path );

if ( !preg_match( 
         '|^\s*require\s*\(?\s*(.+?)/wp-blog-header\.php([\'"])|m', 
         $index_code, 
         $matches 
     ) 
) {
        return false;
}
```

to get the subdirectory where the `wp-blog-header.php` file is located and set it as the `$wp_path`.

Comment: Well annoying then that wp-cli suggests it in the error. But none of the variants work :(

Comment: Yes that's strange. Do you also get the exactly the same errors when trying the alternatives? @janw

Comment: It's the same but without the `-bash: /home/me/domains/example.com/public_html/: is a directory` line.

Comment: yes I excpected the -bash error to vanish there. When I use the wp-skeleton setup, I have to point to the wp/ core folder, not the folder above it containing the wp-config.php file. Not sure if you're using any specific setup @janw

Comment: Yes, I'm using a speketon. adding `...mple.com/public_html/wp` does work. If you'll add this part I'll accept the answer

Comment: great, glad to hear that worked ;-) Sure, I udpated the answer @janw